# How can I catch errors from callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a component with this:

```js
      this.loginService.login(this.user, () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      });
```

And a service with this method:

```js
    login(credentials, callback) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders(credentials ?
            { authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.email + ':' + credentials.password) }
            : {});

        this.http.get(this.API.crudAdmin + 'admin?email=' + credentials.email,
            { headers: headers }).subscribe(response => {
                if (response['name']) {
                    this.authenticated = true;
                } else {
                    this.authenticated = false;
                }
                return callback && callback();
            }, error => {
                throw new Error('Error');
            });
    }
```

How could I catch the error thrown from login method when I call it from the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in an *error callback* function along with the success callback. The error callback would be called when the `GET` request fails:

```
this.loginService.login(this.user,
  () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'),
  //handle the error here, log to an error service etc.
  (err) = > console.error(err)
);
```

On the service side, in the error handler of the `Observable`, you call the `errorCallback` you have passed from the component:

```
login(credentials, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders(credentials ? {
      authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.email + ':' + credentials.password)
    } :
    {});

  this.http.get(this.API.crudAdmin + 'admin?email=' + credentials.email, {
    headers: headers
  }).subscribe(response => {
    if (response['name']) {
      this.authenticated = true;
    } else {
      this.authenticated = false;
    }
    successCallback && successCallback();
  }, 
  errorCallback);
}
```

A traditional try-catch won't work here as this is an asynchronous operation, the catch block won't be able catch the error when the `GET` fails eventually.

This is because the `loginService.login` method returns immediately while the `GET` request is made asynchronously in the background. Any error from the `GET` won't be handled by the `catch` block surrounding the `loginService.login` call.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common pattern to pass the error as the first argument in the callback function. So your login function would look like:

```js
login(credentuals, callback) {
  this.http.get(options).subscribe((response) => {
    // Logic, assuming it was successfuly, call callback with the first argument as null
    callback(null)
  }, (error) => {
    // in the event of an error, pass error exception as the first argument
    callback(error)
  });
}
```

so then you can handle this in your component:

```js
this.loginService.login(credentials, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    // show error dialog, etc
  } else {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your function call in a try/catch block.

```
try {
    this.loginService.login(this.user, () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    });
} catch (error) {
    // do something with the thrown error
}
```

Comment: Won’t help if the error is thrown from *inside* the callback (eg. navigateByURL throws).

Comment: That's true. I didn't see he mentioned the callback in the title, but rather just the error the login method throws in the question body. Either way, the question looks answered already so I'll leave this as is.